# In sum of $n$, $S_n$ =$\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$, so if $r$ is positive and I wanted to find $n$. How do turn $r$ in to non-negative?

Tags: logarithms, geometric-series

I am given this question find the number of term in this geometric series
$3 +1 + \frac{1}{3} , ... , \frac{121}{27}$. So $a=3$ and $r=\frac{1}{3}$ I subbed all the numbers in and I got $\frac{242}{243}-1=-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n,  (n = 5)$. I wanted to use logs to find n but I can't because $\frac{1}{3}$ is negative. So how do you do this question or am I using the right formula of  $S_n =\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ as $\frac{1}{3} <1$?

Comment: Isn't the lhs also negative?

Comment: So I interpret this question as follows: Consider the sequence $a_n = 3\times 3^{-n}$ and
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_n = 3\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{3} \right)^k
$$
We know that $S_n = \frac{121}{27}$ for some $n$. Find this $n$. Am I correct? If my interpretation is correct, I don't quite get how you got the negative sign there, since we're only adding positive numbers together.

Comment: You need to use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr).

Comment: The reduced fraction for $3+1+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{3^n}$ has denominator $3^n$ hence if $S_n=\frac{121}{27}$ then $3^n=27$, that is, $n=3$. Of course, one should then check that $n=3$ is a solution, that is, that $3+1+\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{27}=\frac{121}{27}$, that is, that $3\cdot27+1\cdot27+9+3+1=121$, which happens to be true.

Comment: elementary: $\frac{3\left(1-\left(\frac13\right)^n\right)}{1-\frac13}=\frac{121}{27} \Rightarrow 3^n=3^5 \Rightarrow n=5$.